# Wireless always disconnects with a Broadcom BCM4312

Tags: 12.04, broadcom

I upgraded my Ubuntu 10.10 for Ubuntu 12.04.
I have a Emachines E625

With Ubuntu 12.04 my wireless always disconnects every 10 sec. It didn't do that with 10.10.

Here is my config:

```
Linux sylvain-eMachines-E625 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:54:40 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux    

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1759       1425        333          0         46        925
-/+ buffers/cache:        452       1306
Swap:         1788          0       1788
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
```

I will really enjoy an answer to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Silas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)