# WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resumes

Tags: wireless, broadcom

In Kubuntu, strangely enough, Wifi completely goes off for about 5 to 30 seconds and then reconnects again. What can be cause of this problem?

My Laptop info:
Kubunu 15.10
KDE plasma 5.4.2
Kernel Version 4.2.0-27-generic

let me know which other info I need to share. ([this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632417/14-04-bcm-43142-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-when-too-far) shares alot of info and nobody answered!)

Update 1: output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508]
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Update 2: output of `grep wlan /var/log/kern.log`

```
Feb  7 13:29:45 HP kernel: [   20.420557] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:30:34 HP kernel: [   69.472388] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:30:34 HP kernel: [   69.557596] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:30:41 HP kernel: [   76.132410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:30:49 HP kernel: [   84.516376] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:30:50 HP kernel: [   84.595066] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:48:26 HP kernel: [   20.763486] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:48:31 HP kernel: [   26.496351] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:48:32 HP kernel: [   26.768843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.425032] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.448664] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.453951] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.456283] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.459509] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.459902] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 13:50:02 HP kernel: [  117.459936] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 13:50:05 HP kernel: [  120.472723] wlan0: deauthenticated from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.401202] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.424614] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.427180] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.428251] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.431222] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
Feb  7 13:50:34 HP kernel: [  149.431620] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 14:08:38 HP kernel: [ 1232.119261] wlan0: deauthenticating from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb  7 14:11:40 HP kernel: [   19.752909] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 14:12:37 HP kernel: [   77.492458] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 14:12:37 HP kernel: [   77.555537] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.789036] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.812648] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.815753] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.820065] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.823603] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.823995] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 14:13:18 HP kernel: [  117.824061] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 15:03:55 HP kernel: [   22.797706] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:04:00 HP kernel: [   28.544436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:04:01 HP kernel: [   28.970856] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:04:02 HP kernel: [   30.131941] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.041220] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.064676] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.067027] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.068181] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.071494] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.071893] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 15:05:25 HP kernel: [  113.071925] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 15:38:07 HP kernel: [   21.369331] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:38:13 HP kernel: [   27.096353] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:38:13 HP kernel: [   27.177568] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:38:14 HP kernel: [   28.310506] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:40:39 HP kernel: [  172.965166] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:40:39 HP kernel: [  173.511667] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:41:02 HP kernel: [  195.942446] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:41:03 HP kernel: [  197.518776] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:41:04 HP kernel: [  197.806099] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:41:04 HP kernel: [  198.514786] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.533349] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.556679] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.559227] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.560071] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.563334] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.563767] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 15:41:34 HP kernel: [  228.563807] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 15:48:50 HP kernel: [  664.353899] wlan0: deauthenticating from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Feb  7 15:49:02 HP kernel: [  676.206188] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:38 HP kernel: [  712.508721] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:38 HP kernel: [  712.517050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:39 HP kernel: [  713.469383] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:39 HP kernel: [  713.480442] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:39 HP kernel: [  713.517817] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:39 HP kernel: [  713.536570] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:40 HP kernel: [  714.510608] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:49:40 HP kernel: [  714.516118] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:50:26 HP kernel: [  760.585066] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.608587] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.611016] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.612047] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.615341] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.615782] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 15:50:27 HP kernel: [  760.615823] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 15:57:10 HP kernel: [   20.856551] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:57:16 HP kernel: [   26.592379] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:57:16 HP kernel: [   26.672656] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:57:17 HP kernel: [   27.805317] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:03 HP kernel: [   74.526900] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:04 HP kernel: [   75.229235] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:04 HP kernel: [   75.251292] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:04 HP kernel: [   75.265960] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:07 HP kernel: [   78.177975] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:07 HP kernel: [   78.509149] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:20 HP kernel: [   90.837966] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:21 HP kernel: [   92.520402] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:24 HP kernel: [   94.947817] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:25 HP kernel: [   96.510522] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:58:53 HP kernel: [  124.386939] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.653121] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.676663] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.680144] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.684069] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.687297] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.687698] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 15:59:05 HP kernel: [  135.687742] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Feb  7 16:23:36 HP kernel: [   20.390421] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 16:23:42 HP kernel: [   26.116384] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 16:23:42 HP kernel: [   26.193417] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.340317] wlan0: authenticate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.352602] wlan0: send auth to a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.361461] wlan0: authenticated
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.364150] wlan0: associate with a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (try 1/3)
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.374449] wlan0: RX AssocResp from a4:b1:e9:9c:f0:96 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.374827] wlan0: associated
Feb  7 16:23:43 HP kernel: [   27.374864] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Edit 1: I tried [this asnwer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549238/unable-to-use-wifi-on-lenovo-z5070) but it didnt work.

Edit 2: I collect a set of questions without answers with the same problem of mine:[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689579/wi-fi-disconnects) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730651/ubuntu-14-04-lts-keeps-disconnecting-wifi) [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645835/wifi-is-frequently-disconnecting/646476) [4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721587/wifi-disconnects-after-a-few-hour) [5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677605/ubuntu-14-04-lts-wifi-disconnects-reconnects-constantly) [6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683662/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: It way be a hardware problem or a problem with many acess points around. Did you scan and select a channel correctly?

Comment: When connection goes away, I still can connect with other devices to wifi. Also this problem start to show just today after installing Kubuntu 15.10 so it is a driver problem in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe that's true. But I see no way to fix it. Broadcom wireless adapters are poorly supported in Linux beacause of Broadcom policies.

Comment: Strange enough, I didn't have this problem with Ubuntu 14.10 where I exactly had the same driver.

Comment: Look at the output of `grep wlan /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: I add the output as 2nd update inside the question.

Comment: Try to disable IPV6.

Comment: do you recommend this method? http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04 or I should disable it from system settings?

Comment: You can try either way, but I do not think that will really help.

Comment: Have you tried this: rfkill list up lspci wlan0 nmcli nm ipadresse and it might work fine this way.

Comment: This doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an internet connection:

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

install build-essential and linux-headers

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

install or reinstall wpa_supplicant

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install wpasupplicant
```

install b43 firmware

```
 sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

load the driver

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

and

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

You can reboot

Comment: Seems like a working solution, tnx! I flag all other unanswered similar questions as duplicate so that hopefully this answer can help other similar questions