# Wifi keeps disconnecting in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Output of command `ifconfig`:

[image: img]

Output of command `sudo lshw -C network`:

[image: img]

How can I make my WiFi connections stable and stop them from disconnecting automatically?

Everyone who said it is a duplicate of some other questions , those solution didn't fix my problem :( . Please help

Comment: It would be nice if you paste terminal output as plain text (code formatted) instead of adding screenshots.

Comment: this answer solved my question but I don't know if it is suitable for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resumes

Comment: What should be the output of the last three commands? @Woeitg

Comment: which three  commands?

Comment: load the driver

 
(sudo modprobe b43)

and

(sudo ifdown wlan0)

(sudo ifup wlan0)   @Woeitg

Comment: My problem is not fixed :( @Woeitg

Comment: I dont know about those commands. read the info in my link and bytecommander link