# WiFi disconnecting repeatedly with Ralink rt3920

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

I have two pretty old laptops one is Asus x200ca and another is HP 240. I decided to give them a new life by installing Kubuntu 20.04(as it is good looking and light on resources). Both have the same wireless card that is Ralink rt3920. On both the devices I am facing a problem of frequent wifi disconnections. I mean the wifi is established, device is connected to the router but I loose the internet access and also the cannot connect to these devices via lan (samba, ssh, ftp). That means although the connection is established the device and the router are not interacting with each other. I don't face such issues with any other devices in my house. I also didn't face this issue when these devices were running Windows. I also tried other Ubuntu based distros like PopOS, Zorin lite, elementaryOS, UbuntuDDE, and Ubuntu 20.04 itself. I am facing the same problem on all the distros, even on the distros based on 18.04. Please help me out

`lspci`
Gives the output (only for wireless)
`02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3920 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837882/wifi-keeps-disconnecting-in-ubuntu-16-04) question on askubuntu may help.

Comment: Thanks, It helped

Comment: Glad to know, you can just answer your question below for others to help.